# Perturbative violation of the unitarity: what is it?

Tags: perturbation-theory, unitarity

Consider the Fermi theory:

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{G_{F}}{2\sqrt{2}}\bar{n}\gamma_{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})p \bar{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma_{5})e
$$

The cross section of $2 \to 2$ scattering calculated within the leading order of the perturbation theory grows with energy:
$$
\sigma_{\bar{p}n \to e\bar{\nu}} \sim G_{F}^{2}s
$$
Thus, as is typically said, it violates the unitarity since it breaks down the "tree level unitarity" at high energies.

My question is the following: why the first statement follows from the second statement? Maybe the perturbation theory cannot be considered for energies $s\gtrsim G_{F}^{-1}$, since the effective coupling is $G_{F}s$?

Comment: One assumes you are cool with [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90736/basic-question-about-the-s-matrix-unitarity-and-effective-field-theory)?

Answer (score 1):

"Unitarity" here really just means that all probabilities have to sum to unity in the end.

Obviously a cross section (and hence a probability) that grows linearly with energy is not bounded by 1.